# Yii 1.1 : save data in two table

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new in Yii 1.1 
I want to save one object in two separate table please check my code.

```
$policyMaping = new PolicyRules();
$policyMaping->policy_rules_master_id = $data['policy']['id'];
$policyMaping->rules_id = $newRule->id;
$policyMaping->studio_id = $studio_id;
$policyMaping->policy_type = $data['policy']['name'];
$policyMaping->duration_type = $data['policy']['duration_type'];
$policyMaping->policy_value = $policy;
$policyMaping->created_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$policyMaping->save();

$policyMaping = new PolicyRulesLog();
//$policyMaping->policy_rules_master_id = $data['policy']['id'];
//$policyMaping->rules_id = $newRule->id;
//$policyMaping->studio_id = $studio_id;
//$policyMaping->policy_type = $data['policy']['name'];
//$policyMaping->duration_type = $data['policy']['duration_type'];
//$policyMaping->policy_value = $policy;
//$policyMaping->created_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$policyMaping->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
$policyMaping->save();
```

I have posted my requirement code. There is two table `PolicyRules` and `PolicyRulesLog` both table columns are same except `user_id` I want to save requested data in my both table. I don't want to write same code in separate variable. Please help me.

Comment: Try with this 
`$data = $policyMaping->attributes;
$policyMapingLog = new PolicyRulesLog();
$policyMapingLog->setAttributes($data);`
I think it solve your issue

Comment: @ArshadShaikh I am getting all null value column inserting in my table.

Comment: Ideally, you would use afterSave method in PolicyRules model and fill out the PolicyRulesLog model using `PRL->attributes = PR->attributes;` user_id set and then save.
The second approach would be writing same in the controller, using same attributes() function.

Comment: Wrap it all in transactions, use getters and setters. Write custom method which will store them both and call it whenever you need. Don't do so as you do,I once inherited the same kind of code...

Comment: did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save same data into different tables. I have modified your code. Check the code below and let me know if it works for you.

```
$policyMaping = new PolicyRules();
$policyMaping->policy_rules_master_id = $data['policy']['id'];
$policyMaping->rules_id = $newRule->id;
$policyMaping->studio_id = $studio_id;
$policyMaping->policy_type = $data['policy']['name'];
$policyMaping->duration_type = $data['policy']['duration_type'];
$policyMaping->policy_value = $policy;
$policyMaping->created_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$policyMaping->save(FALSE); // use false parameter to disable validation otherwise just use save only

$policyMapingLog = new PolicyRulesLog();
$policyMapingLog->policy_rules_master_id = $data['policy']['id'];
$policyMapingLog->rules_id = $newRule->id;
$policyMapingLog->studio_id = $studio_id;
$policyMapingLog->policy_type = $data['policy']['name'];
$policyMapingLog->duration_type = $data['policy']['duration_type'];
$policyMapingLog->policy_value = $policy;
$policyMapingLog->created_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$policyMapingLog->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
$policyMapingLog->save(FALSE);
```

In Short you can also use...

```
$policyMaping = new PolicyRules();
$policyMaping->setAttributes($data);
$policyMaping->rules_id = $newRule->id;
$policyMaping->studio_id = $studio_id;
$policyMaping->policy_value = $policy;
$policyMaping->created_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$policyMaping->save(FALSE);

$policyMapingLog = new PolicyRulesLog();
$policyMapingLog->setAttributes($data);
$policyMapingLog->rules_id = $newRule->id;
$policyMapingLog->studio_id = $studio_id;
$policyMapingLog->policy_value = $policy;
$policyMapingLog->created_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$policyMapingLog->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
$policyMapingLog->save(FALSE);
```

Comment: You are right. But you have repeated `rules_id`, `studio_id`, `policy_value` etc.